# CSS Organigram issue

Tags: html, css

Well, I'm using this as an example of [what i want to do](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) but, when i have a lot of elemnts at the same level, te last branches goes down and i want that my div expands when it overflows, I've tried with overflow-x: auto;  overflow:auto; but it doesn't work. I'm retrieveng my "leafs" from a list so i don't know how many elements will be there.

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left; text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
  right: auto; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
  border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The biggest issue is that you are trying to make the parent expand to fit all of it's child elements, which are absolutely positioned, which can't be done in pure CSS. There are a number of hacks you can do using 'ghost' elements and spans that fit, but no good ones. Are you against using JS? It would be pretty easy to solve that way.

Comment: @Rockster160 No, I'm not against using JS if that can fix that, if you could help me i'll be very glad

Comment: Posted an answer- and may I add: Well done! Very cool seeing charts like this without using Canvas or SVG's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS could have help too:

- `display:table;` it lets container shrink/expands to fit content size. if a `width` is specified, it can still expand unless `table-layout` is set to `fixed`
- `white-space:nowrap;` will keep any inline (or inline boxes) on a single line.
- `display:inline-block;` instead `float`. used with `white-space` it will not wrap/break into new lines.
- `font-size`, one of the way to deal with `white-space` from code indentation that shows up where tags are behaving/set as inline boxes.

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.tree {
  display:table;/* added let me grow as much as needed*/
  }
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
  white-space:nowrap;/* added */
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  display:table;/* added idem as for parent*/
  font-size:0;/* added because of white-space, remove it to see what it does  */
}

.tree li {
  display:inline-block;/* added instead float*/
  font-size:1rem;/* added */
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
  right: auto; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
  border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

-- USES JQUERY --

It's not the prettiest, but this seems to work:

```
total = 0
$('li:not(:has(ul))').each(function() {total += $(this).outerWidth() + 10})
$('.tree').width(total)
```

What it's doing is finding each 'child' that doesn't have any children. So the lowest level of each chain. `$('li:not(:has(ul))')`

Then sums up the `outerWidth` of each of those, plus a little bit of padding to account for margins.

Finally, sets the width of the container `.tree` to the size we just calculated.

Comment: You bet. :) Happy to help!